# After Unplugging my laptop and got shut down it never charges to any % and shuts down instantly if not in plug

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery

So this strange thing happened today:

Had to move to another room and unplugged my laptop to fix the wires etc. After some hour or so it shut down because, well.. it wasn't in charge, and when I put it back in, the Battery always says "Estimating" in the ubuntu indicato. And INSTANTLY shuts down when I unplug it (even plugged, it shuts down if I do something demanding).

I tried close it and charging it while shut down but same thing happens.

Also unplugged the battery and replugged it nothing happened

It's like battery died in one day. Is that it?

Just look to a fresh battery?

Comment: If you remove the battery entirely, plug-in the device, are you able to turn the device on?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, and it's working.

Comment: So the problem is your battery and/or the charging circuit.  Only one of those can be fixed